# Remove Log off button

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, remove, logoff

I am using a server with Windows Server 2008. I don't want anyone to log off, because it would stop very important programs.
But I can't change the Log Off button to anything (the drop down menu is grey), and thus I can't disabled it (I already tried the gpedit.msc thing, it doesn't seem to work...).
Note that I can't log off or restart the server.
Is there a way to solve this problem ?

Comment: The fix here is likely a more sensible setup. Why are non-admins logging into an account with the ability to shut down critical processes?

Comment: I did find this in the gpedit.msc..
run gpedit.msc  -> User Configuration -> Administrative templates -> Start Menu and Taskbar -> Add Logoff to the Start Menu . Open this option to enable/disable the Logoff option

Comment: Other than a more sensible setup, like either ceejayoz or topus suggested, you can change the background image to harshly-worded warning about using a cattle prod on anyone who logs out of or shuts down the system.  I can give you some pointers on the best ways to do that, too... it's pretty straightforward, but if you want it to ***really*** hurt, there are a couple important details you need to know about how to use the cattle-prod.

Comment: Why are non-admins even logging onto a server, unless it's a Terminal Server?

Answer (score 6):

Why not set those "important programs" to run as services rather than as programs as the logged in user?  This would have them running whether anyone is logged in or not logged in at all.